# How to make header only responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

There's an old website that isn't optimized for small screens (`PHP` + `HTML`/`CSS`/`JS`).

The `<meta name="viewport"...>` tag is missing in the head section, so the page content is displayed by adjusting to the screen size - it turns out to be tiny. The site is far from being fully adapted for mobile devices, but there's a desire to make at least the header adaptive.

That is, it's assumed that when opened on a mobile device, the header will look like a rectangle with a logo and a "hamburger" icon that's commonly used in such cases. Pressing the hamburger icon, we see a modal window with menu items.

My knowledge is not enough.

Did I understand correctly that without the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` tag, media queries and container queries don't work?

If I specify the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` tag in the head section, it turns out that now all pages need to be adapted.

If I don't specify the `<meta name="viewport"...>`, then the statements in media queries are not applied.

How can I make only the header adaptive for now?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly.
You are going to make a menu responsive.
that when the site is displayed on a mobile phone, the menu should be in the form of a hamburger.
Exactly you should use `media query`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   body {
     background-color: light blue;
   }
}
```

Please pay attention to this code.
`max-width` is used.
**This means that if your page width is smaller than 600px, the body color will change.**
Another value can be given to him: `min-width`
**That is, if it is greater than one number, an action will occur.**
I feel that you also understand, it seems to work the same as the conditional rings.

You can have your own main menu.
And create your own burger menu too.
Just `display: none.`
And using `media-query`, say that if the value is smaller than a certain limit, `display: block`.
and display your main menu to none.

It means that you have **created both**, but you specified a **condition for their display**.
And that you can define the `max-width` number according to the users of your site, which type of device they visit the most.
You can also from: **`w3school.com`**
get help

Sorry for the long explanation, I tried to make it clear for you.

Comment: sorry,  i suspect that your answer is ai-generated (tone of voice, typos in color's value)

Anyway you suggest to use media queries but as i understood i should to provide viewport meta tag. But in that case i should provide responsive statements for all site content (that's what i try to avoid)

Comment: No, I wrote this text myself, but I had a little restriction because I sent it with the phone, and in some parts I got help from the translator.
Honestly, you can't do this using Meta. I had already come to this problem. And I saw this is the only way for me. Of course, there may be the second way, for example you put the main menu and your Multi -style menu in a style. what does it mean? That is, use both hamburgers or Side-Menu.

Comment: oh, my excuse. I'm not sure i got your point, but i cant' use meta viewport tag because all other blocks require css adjustments. Without meta viewport tag media queries are not applied

Answer (score 0):

> this is a responsive header

```
>  --style.css--
```

- {box-sizing: border-box;}

  body {
  margin: 0;
  }

  .header {
  over-flow: hidden;
  background-color:
  padding:20px 10px;
  }

  .header a {
  flote: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  }

  .header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  }

  .header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  }

  .header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  }

  .header-right {
  float: right;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px;) {
  .header a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  }

  .header-right {
  float: none;
  }
  }

  --HTML code--

  LOGO
      
        Home
        contact
        About